# How to find the determinant using elementary row operations of this 5x5 matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I tried to calculate this $5\times5$ matrix with type III operation, but I found the determinant answer of the $4\times4$ matrix obtained by deleting row one and column three of this matrix is not same.

Original $5\times5$ matrix:
[image: Original 5x5 A matrix]

$4\times4$ $B$ Matrix:
[image: 4x4 B Matrix]

Can somebody help me how to solve this questions with step-by-step?

Thanks for advising!!

Comment: What is a Type III operation? What do you mean by "it's not the same"? The same as what?

Comment: The Type III operation – addition of a scalar 
multiple of one row to another row. This 
does not change the determinant.